# R using gsub in a loop

Tags: r, loops, gsub

I have a following vector of column names:

```
plot_variables <- c("Ser predicted (g/L)", "Ser initial (g/L)", "Ser experimental (g/L)", "Glu predicted (g/L)", "Glu initial (g/L)", "Glu experimental (g/L)", Pro predicted (g/L), ...)
```

And I have a glossary of those short names:

```
df_glossary <- data.frame(
  short = c("Cys", "Pro", "Phe", "Ser", "Glu", "Glc", ...),
  full = c("Cysteine", "Proline", "Phenylalanine", "Serine", "Glutamate", "Glucose", ...),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I would like to match those two and have something like:

```
names_matching <- data.frame(
variable = c("Ser predicted (g/L)", "Ser initial (g/L)", "Ser experimental (g/L)", ...),
label = c("Serine predicted (g/L)", "Serine initial (g/L)", "Serine experimental (g/L)", ...)
)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it than this:

```
pl<-unlist(plot_variables)

pl<-sapply(1:nrow(df_glossary) , function(x){
    pl<<- gsub(df_glossary$short[x], df_glossary$full[x],  pl, fixed = TRUE)
    })

pl <- pl[,nrow(df_glossary)] %>% data.frame()

names_matching <- cbind(plot_variables %>% data.frame, pl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `gsubfn` in the `gsubfn` package. If you want to read the keys and values from another data frame, you'll have some wrangling to do, but in general here's how it works:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> gsubfn('[Ser|Glu|Pro]*', 
     list('Ser'='Serine','Glu'='Glutamate','Pro'='Proline'), plot_variables)
[1] "Serine predicted (g/L)"       "Serine initial (g/L)"        
[3] "Serine experimental (g/L)"    "Glutamate predicted (g/L)"   
[5] "Glutamate initial (g/L)"      "Glutamate experimental (g/L)"
[7] "Proline predicted (g/L)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question, would this work?

```
df_glossary <- data.frame(
  shortnames = c("Cys", "Pro", "Phe", "Ser", "Glu", "Glc"),
  full = c("Cysteine", "Proline", "Phenylalanine", "Serine", "Glutamate", "Glucose"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
plot_variables <- c("Ser predicted (g/L)", "Ser initial (g/L)", "Ser experimental (g/L)", "Glu predicted (g/L)", "Glu initial (g/L)", "Glu experimental (g/L)", "Pro predicted (g/L)")
suffixes = c("predicted (g/L)", "initial (g/L)", "experimental (g/L)")

df_glossary %>% rowwise %>% 
    do(data.frame(short=.$short, full=.$full, suffix=suffixes )) %>%
    mutate(label=paste(full, suffix))

short   full    suffix  label
Cys Cysteine    predicted (g/L) Cysteine predicted (g/L)
Cys Cysteine    initial (g/L)   Cysteine initial (g/L)
Cys Cysteine    experimental (g/L)  Cysteine experimental (g/L)
Pro Proline predicted (g/L) Proline predicted (g/L)
Pro Proline initial (g/L)   Proline initial (g/L)
Pro Proline experimental (g/L)  Proline experimental (g/L)
Phe Phenylalanine   predicted (g/L) Phenylalanine predicted (g/L)
Phe Phenylalanine   initial (g/L)   Phenylalanine initial (g/L)
Phe Phenylalanine   experimental (g/L)  Phenylalanine experimental (g/L)
Ser Serine  predicted (g/L) Serine predicted (g/L)
Ser Serine  initial (g/L)   Serine initial (g/L)
Ser Serine  experimental (g/L)  Serine experimental (g/L)
Glu Glutamate   predicted (g/L) Glutamate predicted (g/L)
Glu Glutamate   initial (g/L)   Glutamate initial (g/L)
Glu Glutamate   experimental (g/L)  Glutamate experimental (g/L)
Glc Glucose predicted (g/L) Glucose predicted (g/L)
Glc Glucose initial (g/L)   Glucose initial (g/L)
Glc Glucose experimental (g/L)  Glucose experimental (g/L)
```

Comment: Not quite, your suggestion creates all possible options, while I would pretty much like to rename only existing columns from `Ser predicted` to `Serine predicted` and so on